# How to flatten fields with the same names

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm using `itext 7.1.8` and I need to flatten a document that contains fields with the same names.
I create the document like the following:

```
private static PdfDocument createPdfDocument(final String name, final int countFields) {
        PdfDocument pdf;
        try {
            final FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(name + ".pdf");
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(os);
            pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);


            final PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.addNewPage();

            final float height = pdfPage.getCropBox().getHeight();

            final PdfTextFormField txt1Fld = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, new Rectangle( 100, height - 100, 200, 18), "Text_1");
            txt1Fld.setValue("Hello");

            for (int i = 0; i < countFields; i++) {
                PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true)
                        .addField(txt1Fld, i == 0 ? pdfPage : pdf.addNewPage());
            }

            pdf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pdf = null;
        }
        return pdf;
    }
```

after that, I'm trying to flatten document like the following:

```
private static void flattenPdf(String name, String flattenName) {
        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(flattenName + ".pdf");
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(name + ".pdf");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os);
            final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
            final PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
            acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
            acroForm.flattenFields();
            pdfDocument.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String flattenName = "ItextPdfTwoFields";

    System.out.println("Create " + flattenName + ".pdf");
    createPdfDocument(flattenName, 2);
    System.out.println(flattenName + ".pdf created successfully");
    System.out.println("Trying to flat " + flattenName + "_flatten.pdf...");
    flattenPdf(flattenName, flattenName + "_flatten");
}
```

and after flattening I get the document which contains one flatten fields but I have to get two flatten fields.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would definitely recommend using the latest version which is 7.1.12. Merely using that version is not enough though and you will need to write some additional code to create a form field with several widgets, i.e. shared value across several field representations. The code for flattening is just fine and we just need to modify the code to create a document because what happens in your current code is that the same field is added to two pages and the association between widget annotations and pages is not consistent. Instead of this code:

```
final PdfTextFormField txt1Fld = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, new Rectangle( 100, height - 100, 200, 18), "Text_1");
txt1Fld.setValue("Hello");

for (int i = 0; i < countFields; i++) {
    PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true)
            .addField(txt1Fld, i == 0 ? pdfPage : pdf.addNewPage());
}
```

We need to create a field only once, then add widgets to the field for the remaining pages (except the first one) and associate pages with the widgets (add widget annotation to the corresponding page). Finally, we set the value to the field which generates appearances for all the widget annotations and we add the field to the form. Here is the code:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( 100, height - 100, 200, 18);
final PdfTextFormField txt1Fld = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, rect, "Text_1");

for (int i = 1; i < countFields; i++) {
    PdfWidgetAnnotation annotation = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(rect);
    annotation.makeIndirect(pdf);
    txt1Fld.addKid(annotation);
}

for (int i = 0; i < countFields; i++) {
    if (pdf.getNumberOfPages() <= i) {
        pdf.addNewPage();
    }
    pdf.getPage(i + 1).addAnnotation(txt1Fld.getWidgets().get(i));
}

txt1Fld.setValue("Hello");

PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true).addField(txt1Fld, pdfPage);
```